# Pandas conversion month name to date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When reading a csv file, the date column is set as month name (Jul-20 for July 2020), and when using `parse_dates=True`, Pandas converts it to `01-07-2020`. How can I force pandas to convert it to end of month (ie, `31-07-2020`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using `monthend` from `pandas.tseries.offsets`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
import pandas as pd


print(df)

       month  
0 2020-07-01
1 2020-08-02 

df['month_end'] =  df['month'] + MonthEnd(1)

print(df)
      month  month_end
0 2020-07-01 2020-07-31
1 2020-08-02 2020-08-31
```

Comment: it will work in this only because the dates are always the first date of the month. in case of the last day of the month, month_end will jump to the next month

Comment: @nimrodz yep, but I don't think that matters in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt calendar and datetime modules and write your own apply method to achieve the desired result.

```
import calendar
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def parse_my_date(date):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%B-%Y')
    last_day = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=last_day-1)
    return date

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: parse_my_date(x))
```